# PHP sprintf and scope

Tags: php, scope, printf

I've been rearranging some code for better readability/maintainability, but hit an issue I can't quite figure out.

The original code was basically as follows:

```
$myFormat = '/* HTML structure */';

try {
    // SQL queries
    // Sorting and storing relevant data
    echo sprintf($myFormat,$1,$2...$N);
}
catch{
    // Error handling if there's a db issue
}
```

Which worked but wasn't very well organised, given that a load of unnecessary stuff was contained within the SQL-oriented try/catch block.

So I changed it to the following:

```
$myFormat = '/* HTML structure */';

function dataHandling($a1,$a2...){
    // Sorting and storing relevant data
    echo sprintf($myFormat,$1,$2...$N);
}

try {
    // SQL queries
    dataHandling($s1,$s2...);
}
catch{
    // Error handling if there's a db issue
}
```

And everything appears to work except for the `echo sprintf` line inside `dataHandling`, which is fairly significant. I've only been writing php for a for days and assume it's a scope issue, but I can't find any info addressing a similar issue.

Comment: `$1` is not a valid variable name, is that really what you meant to write?

Comment: No, I know it's not - it's purely for summarisation purposes.

Comment: It's really hard to know what the actual problems are with your code when you post something completely different "for summarization purposes".

Comment: I understand your point.I felt it necessary to reduce to pseudo-code, though, as I was certain that the issue lay solely with the line in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `$myFormat` as a parameter. Also, the parameters to `sprintf` must match the function parameters.

```
function dataHandling($format, $a1,$a2...){
    // Sorting and storing relevant data
    echo sprintf($format,$a1,$a2...);
}

try {
    dataHandling($myFormat, $s1,$s2...);
}
catch{
    // Error handling if there's a db issue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a **global** keyword inside the function.

```
function dataHandling($a1, $a2 ...){
      global $myFormat;
      //remaining code
}
```

For more information on scope check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) out.

Comment: If it was a scope related issue, this should have done it as far as I know. And you are sure the original code was working fine ?

Comment: I assumed it was a scope issue. Yes, the original code worked just fine, as stated.

Comment: @verism This should have worked, you must have done it wrong. Was the original code inside another function? If so, you also need a `global` statement in that function.

Comment: The original code wasn't inside another function; just php tags. I tried this approach again (just to be sure), but it still didn't fix the issue.